# How do I remove the "Productivity" group header from Windows 10's Start menu?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, start-menu

By default Windows 10's Start menu mandates the use of groups, ensuring that the Start menu always consists of at least one group. However, grouped tiles are not a feature I need and I would rather just place all my most-used tiles directly onto the Start menu. The closest I can get to this is placing all the tiles in a single large group. However, the problem that I then have is that this group's header still remains, called "Productivity" by default.

[image]

If it's not possible to disable the Start menu's groups feature entirely, how can I get rid of the redundant group header and free up the space it's taking up?

Comment: @Ramhound You can clear the header name, but it doesn't remove the header itself, as it's still there when hovered over and the space it takes up remains there. Actually removing the header should cause the rest of the tiles to shift up - as is the default behaviour for tiles and tile groups - to be flush with the hamburger menu icon instead of leaving an unsightly empty gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I remove the “Productivity” group header from Windows 10's Start menu?

All you have to do is click on the words "Productivity" and clear the text.

> how can I get rid of the redundant group header and free up the space it's taking up?

You can get rid of the words, but you will be unable to get rid of the unnamed group, if you want that gone you will have to use a Start Menu replacement program.

> You can clear the header name, but it doesn't remove the header itself, as it's still there when hovered over and the space it takes up remains there.

Based on your last description, want isn't possible without a third-party program, the best you can do with native functionality is remove the group name.  This might change once `Windows 10 version 2004` is released.

Comment: Do you have a source for the "This might change once Windows 10 version 2004 is released" claim?

Comment: @Hashim - No;  I know that Cortana will be it's own application.  I know Microsoft is working on Start Menu design changes for it's dual-screen Surface product.  I know that the Start Menu has evolved significantly over the last 4 years.  **I don't have a single source that indicates all of that, specifically, I don't have a source I am willing to quote.**